# SimpleMembershipProvider? Universal Providers? WebSecurity? I can't follow a tutorial because of those

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

I'm following Pluralsights MVC4 Essentials course. In the video about authorization it enables the `DefaultRoleProvider` in the `Web.config` (which wasn't present altough I created the project with the same MVC4 Internet template. After installing the Universal Providers via nuget, I followed the tutorial and changed the `Seed()` method to generate a user and assigning a role.

```
if (!Roles.RoleExists("Admin"))
{
    Roles.CreateRole("Admin");
}

if (Membership.GetUser("sallen") == null)
{
    Membership.CreateUser("sallen", "password");
    Roles.AddUserToRole("sallen", "admin");
}
```

Starting the application and trying to login, I was greeted with the `To call this method, the "Membership.Provider" property must be an instance of "ExtendedMembershipProvider".` message, for which google presents a lot of hits. [This article by Jon Galloway](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx) seems to explain the issue, but his solution seems cryptic to me:

> If you want to use the new `AccountController`, you'll either need to use the `SimpleMembershipProvider` or another valid `ExtendedMembershipProvider`. This is pretty straightforward.

Alright, where do I get it?

---

A workaround is using `SimpleMembership` and `SimpleRoleProvider` instead of the `DefaultRoleProvider`.. in `Web.config`, initializing the database connection in the `seed()` method

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection(
            "DefaultConnection",
            "UserProfile",
            "UserId",
            "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
```

And using

```
if (!WebSecurity.UserExists("sallen"))
{
      WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount("sallen", "password");
      Roles.AddUserToRole("sallen", "admin");          
}
```

to generate my user.

---

Is this the SimpleMembershipProvider I need to use? Is it the usual way to use authorization? Why is provider included in the template not an `ExtendedMembershipProvider` and where can I get one? **Why can the tutorial use the template without getting the error?**

Comment: The course you're following on pluralsight uses the simple role & membership providers. If you can't find their sections in the web.config file you can always just add them yourself and the framework will do all the work for you.
In most cases using the simple providers will be sufficient

Comment: [I don't think so](http://imgur.com/mde72Bv).